# Create a polygon from WKT format in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, point-in-polygon, well-known-text

I have a query file in WKT format that contain X and Y coordinate. I want to write code in PyQGIS to create a polygon shapefile from the query file.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the Plugin **QuickWKT**

1. Go to the Plugins -> Manage and Install Plugins..
2. Install **QuickWKT**

[image]

3. Open the plugin **QuickWKT**
4. Select polygon from WKT

[image]

5. Click OK and you will your Polygon

[image]

If you want to add the polygon from PyQGIS, it is the code that can help you:

```
mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:4326", "Name", "Memory")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)

coords = [(30,10), (10,20), (20,40), (40,40), (30,10)] 
polygon = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY( [[ QgsPointXY( pair[0], pair[1] ) for pair in coords ]])

feature = QgsFeature()
feature.setGeometry(polygon)
mem_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feature])
mem_layer.updateFields()
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you very much Mr. Galindo

Comment: You are welcome @FrancisAkunyagra, if you can mark the questions as answered, it will be helpful

Have a good one ;)